# How can I add more servers to SQL Server?

Tags: ssms

I want to add more server names to SQL Server login

[image]

Comment: Then connect to the instances. That's when SSMS caches the server name.

Answer (score 0):

Management Studio remembers logins you've used before. Connect to a server manually, and it will be available to choose from the list next time.